# Cut off a ntfs partition and repair it later

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, partition-recovery, testdisk, ntfs-3g

I have a semi theoretical question regarding ntfs partitions.

Assume we create a ntfs partition inside a file

```
    dd if=/dev/zero of=test.img count=40960
    mkfs.ntfs -F test.img
```

for testing purposes i've added some files

```
    sudo mount -o loop test.img mnt
    mkdir -p mnt/test_dir/doc
    echo "this is a test file" > mnt/test_dir/doc/README.txt
    sudo umount mnt
```

so here comes my question. Assume i have just one part of my partition

```
    dd if=test.img of=test_part.img count=40952
```

is it possible to repair this part, in order to mount it again.

In my understanding in the test_part.img one cluster is missing, since the `count` parameter is 40952, which is 8 less than the original size. And with a sector size of 512, 8*512=4096 is one ntfs cluster.

I've tried the `ntfsfix` utility which did not work.

I've also looked into the documentation of `testdisk` and it seems you can change the partition geometry manually with this tool. However i had no success.

So please help me. Is there a way to repair test_part.img so that i can mount it again and get the README.txt file.

Comment: AFAIR CloneZilla uses [ntfsresize](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsresize) for similar cases, you could give it a try.

Comment: Yey! Thank you it worked. I hope this will also work for my real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>(reposting my comment as an answer</sup>

As far as I remember CloneZilla uses [ntfsresize](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsresize) for similar cases, you could give it a try.

It's as simple as running:

```
ntfsresize /dev/sda1
```

Where `sda1` is the partition you want to fix. You'll need root privileges.

Comment: After further investigation, i've found out that `ntfsresize` does not completely fix the problem. When running `ntfsresize -s 6709248 test_part.img` i'm able to mount the partition and the test file is still there. However `ntfsinfo -m test_part.img` returns that the volume size is clusters is 5119, which is the same as of the original non damaged image. After running `ntfsfix` on test_part.img, the volume size in clusters is displayed correctly, however `parted` still reports a size of 21.0 MB.

Comment: Ok, i think it's correct though. I've doublechecked the size in bytes and it seems all right.